# Some true-or-false questions about matrices

Tags: matrices

I have some true/false questions about matrices that I got wrong and I'm trying to figure out why:

1. If AB = BA and if A is invertible, then A is always square.

Answer: I said true because the only matricies that can have AB = BA are square ones right? What does the invertible part have to do with this?

2. Eigenvectors of an nxn matrix A forms a basis for straight real numbers to the power of n.

I said True but I am not sure why this is false.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assume that $A$ is $m \times n$. Then $B$ has to be $n \times k$ and $AB$ is $m \times k$. If we look at the converse product $BA$, we see that $k=m$ and the product is $n \times n$. Since $AB=BA$, we get $m=k=n$, so $A$ is square. You are right that the assumption that $A$ is invertible is not necessary here. However, it is actually sufficient in itself. We only talk about inverses for square matrices, so if it is invertible, it is square.
2. This one is not generally true. Not at all matrices have a basis of eigenvectors. The ones that do are called diagonalizible.